# WordPress: Web Form with Image/File Submission

Tags: wordpress

First of all, I am absolutely new to WP.

I am hoping to build a site using WP and figured out how to manage every thing except one feature. The feature that is required is to be able to submit a form with files (images in particular) by a non member.

For example, you should be able to visit the site and fill a form and submit your image along it.

Is it possible to upload files as above? How is this achievable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not a wordpress coder , I would sugest you use a plugin for that .

Some options :
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/user-submitted-posts/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tdo-mini-forms/

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/quick-post-widget/

http://www.gravityforms.com/category/features/

and many more ..

read also this tutorial : http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/allow-users-to-submit-images-your-site/ - it is not for VISITORS but for registered users - but it might help you to understand what is needed to be done .

Answer (score 1):

I would use the [Contact Form 7 plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/contact-form-7/) to do this, as it's extremely easy.

In the plugin settings you'll be able to choose what parts of the form you'd like to include, adding a way to upload is one of those options.  You can even limit the type of file that is being used as well the max file size.

Once you create a form in the settings, you just use its shortcode to add it to your Wordpress page.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upload file, but it is not a Wordpress specific solution, unless you want to use a plugin. You can code html/php as per usual to achieve it:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

To embed it on a page, you can create a Page in Wordpress, and assign it a custom page template that you create with the upload form:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Creating_Your_Own_Page_Templates

Comment: Thats how I am currently planning to implement it, but for it I will have to post to a url on a sub-domain. For ex: submit.my-site.com/submit.php. But was wondering if some thing is available within WP.